# Htaccess rewrite url only in one folder

Tags: .htaccess

I useing this code in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /etel.php?q=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

This control this

```
domain.com/etel.php?q=501&n=Beef
to this:
domain.com/501/Beef
```

But if I open the [partner] folder without index.php the htacces open the etel.php. How can I limit that rewrite rule to the parent folder locked out other folder files?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule with these 2 `RewriteCond` to exclude existing files and directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /etel.php?q=$1&n=$2 [L,QSA]
```